# Wear A Hat To/Into

Tags: prepositions, headlinese

I have a question about the pattern "wear [something]  into/to a [place]/[event]"

1. wear a hat ***to*** a party
2. wear a hat ***into*** a party
3. wear a hat ***to*** a stadium
4. wear a hat ***into*** a stadium

Do "to" or "into" make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

To *wear X to Y* ordinarily implies that you put X on as appropriate dress for travelling to or being present at Y; for instance

> I wore a hat to the party ... (*because it was fancy dress*)
>   I wore a hat to the stadium ... (*because it was very chilly*)

The expression may also be used with the implication that you negligently wore inappropriate dress:

> My dear, he actually wore a *bowler hat* to the opera!

*Into* would replace *to* only in speaking of your wearing X while (and after) entering an enclosure. So it would be possible to speak of wearing a hat *into* a stadium. It is difficult to imagine why you would mention wearing a hat into a stadium; but it is easy to imagine that wearing a hat into a place where you ought to remove it would provoke comment:

> My dear, he actually wore his hat into church!

But I cannot come up with a situation in which you might say that you wore a hat *into a party*.

Comment: So this might be [wrong](http://www.washingtonpost.com/sports/dcunited/netherlands-wears-black-hat-into-world-cup-semifinal-vs-argentina/2014/07/08/2b9850b0-06e0-11e4-9a71-264773a2ffc8_story.html):  
"Netherlands ***wears*** black hat ***into*** World Cup semifinal vs. Argentina"

Comment: @meatie: Stadium is implied in that title, we know the match took place in a stadium. But are you aware that  *wear a black hat* is a set phrase? When someone is said to *wear a black hat* it doesn't necessarily mean he wears a hat but that he is behaving as the bad guy. On the opposite someone who is described as *wearing a white hat*  can mean he is the good honourable guy.  StoneyB will probably expand on that when he gets back to his computer. That could be a nice ELL question/answer.

Comment: @meatie: [This article](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/what_does_white_hat_and_black_hat_mean/) is the best I could find to explain the metaphoric use of *white hat* and *black hat* which is quite common in internet slang and marketing. The point of the Washington Post article you're linking to is (as far as my very poor understanding of football can tell) to demonstrate the Netherlands team are behaving like villains.

Comment: @Laure Admirably put. If meatie doesn't ask the question I will, and you can answer it!

Comment: @Laure So, it should really be "wear black hats ***to*** the semifinal", not "into"?

Comment: @meatie Actually, the sense is that right now [at the time this was written], as they  are "going into" (=about to play but not yet playing) the semifinal match, they are "wearing black hats". All this is obscured by the very compressed syntax of headlinese, which you cannot take as a model of either spoken or written English.